# How to insert a dynamic id to table in sql?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to add to a table in my DB ("InjuryScenario") a dynamic id (because i work with visual studio c#) and i tried this:

```
declare @InjuryScenarioTMPp int; 
set @InjuryScenarioTMPp = (select MAX (InjuryScenario_id) from InjuryScenario) +1; 
print @InjuryScenarioTMPp;
```

when i printed it, it doesn't show me anything.
when i tried to add a row to the table and i tried the 3 rows (up) again it does print "2".
maybe when i don't have any rows in the table it doesn't know how to do (NULL+1)?
does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of database would you like to use. For example, in MySQL you have to use AUTO INCREMENT on one field. But in Postgres or in Oracle, you should create first a sequence and later than add the next value of this sequence to new record.

Comment: I'm using SQL (not MySQL). I don't want to use the auto increment, i want to use the 3 rows i wrote and to know what to add so that it will work

Answer (score 0):

A `NULL`value is an unknown value, and the result of arithmetic on unknown values is also unknown. What you can do is to use either the`COALESCE`or the`ISNULL`function to replace the `NULL`value with `0`when you use it:

```
declare @InjuryScenarioTMPp int; 
set @InjuryScenarioTMPp = (select ISNULL(MAX(InjuryScenario_id),0) from InjuryScenario) + 1; 
print @InjuryScenarioTMPp;
```

See MSDN: [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

For an example:

```
declare @i int
set @i = null
select @i+1, coalesce(@i, 0)+1, isnull(@i, 0)+1
set @i = 1
select @i+1, coalesce(@i, 0)+1, isnull(@i, 0)+1
```

Output:

```
----------- ----------- -----------
NULL        1           1

(1 row(s) affected)


----------- ----------- -----------
2           2           2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: @user3082812 If me answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.